# Push and Pull elements in Array in NodeJS API call

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my app I use Mongoose to create schemas. I have a user Schema, and a Tickit Schema. Each time a user creates a tickit I want to add the id of the tickit to the 'tickits' array on my user schema, as seen below. The code half works - when I create a tickit, that id goes to the user tickits array - but when I delete the tickit, that id isn't removed from array.

Tickit.js

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;
var tickitSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    author : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    comments: [{body:"string", by: Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tickit', tickitSchema);
```

User.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
var Tickit   = require('../models/Tickit');

var userSchema = new Schema({
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
    tickits      : [Tickit.tickitSchema]

});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

My functions for creating and deleting the tickits are below:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var tickit    = new Tickit(req.body);
    var user      = req.user;
    tickit.author = user._id;
    user.update({tickits : {id : tickit._id}}, {$push: {tickits: { id: tickit._id}}},function (err) {
        if (err) 
            return res.send(err);
    }); 
    user.save();
    tickit.save(function(err, tickits) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.json(tickits);
        }
    });
};

exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
    var tickit_id = req.params.tickit_id;
    req.user.update({tickits : {id : tickit_id}}, {$pull: {tickits: { id: tickit_id}}},function (err) {
        if (err) 
            return res.send(err);
    });
    req.user.save();

    Tickit.remove({_id : req.params.tickit_id}, function(err, tickit) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        Tickit.find(function(err, tickits) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(tickits);
        });
    });   
}
```

Perhaps i'm going about this the wrong way but I've been trying for hours and any help would be really great.

Comment: In ```req.user.update``` if you change the callback to ```function (err, numAffected)``` then output numAffected, is it returning a 1?

Comment: Hi Duane, numAffected does return a 1 for me. After I create the tickit, the user tickit array looks like this:
    `"tickits" : { "id" : ObjectId("5523f40bd19fe9354af08a81") }`
but when I delete the tickit, then check the tickit object on the user, it looks like this:
    `"tickits" : [ { "id" : ObjectId("5523f40bd19fe9354af08a81") } ]`

Comment: Try setting the options for `update`  to `{new: true}` to ensure the modified document is the one returned. I also submitted an answer to show a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with the async nature of [`save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save). Also, cleaned up the schema a bit to help clarify.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var tickitSchema = Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  author : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  comments: [{
    body: String,
    by: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }]
});

var userSchema = Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  tickits: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tickit'
  }]
});

module.export.create = function createTickit(req, res) {
  var tickit = Tickit(req.body);
  tickit.author = req.user;
  // Save the ticket first to ensure it exists
  tickit.save(function (err, tickit) {
    if (err || tickit === null) { return res.send(err || new Error('Ticket was not saved but there was no error...odd')); }

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, {$push: {tickits: tickit}}, {new: true}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return res.send(err) };

      res.json(ticket); // or whatever else you want to send
    });
  });
};

module.export.destroy = function destroyTickit(req, res) {
  // Remove the ticket first to ensure it is removed
  Tickit.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.tickit_id, function (err, tickit) {
    if (err || tickit === null) { return res.send(err || new Error('Ticket was not removed but there was no error...odd')); }

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, {$pull: {tickits: tickit.id}}, {new: true}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return res.send(err) };

      res.json(ticket); // or whatever else you want to send
    });
  });
};
```

This will do the basic create/destroy but without any security controls (ensuring who has the right to destroy a ticket, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Jason for taking the time to provide a great answer. The code you provided works exactly as I need it. It seems like a better approach than the method I was using before. Cheers!